# Is there a work-around for "File size limit exceeded" errors when using db_dump185

Tags: berkeleydb

Has anyone ever attempted to upgrade an old Berkeley database that must be dumped via db_dump185?

When I try to dump a database containing comments from a website, as follows:

```
$ bash-3.2$ db_dump185 -f comment.dump comment.db
```

I get this error:

```
File size limit exceeded (core dumped)
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

---

Here is out output of `ulimit -a`:

```
$ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) 200000
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) 200000
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 32743
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 200000
open files                      (-n) 100
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 20
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 200000
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

---

And this is the database:

```
$ ls -l comment.db 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 daiello staff 184393728 Jan 12 2012 comment.db
```

---

I want to make sure that this question gets an answer.  What @Alan suggested `db_dump185 comment.db | cat > comment.dump` really helped.  Continuing with the dump eventually consumed all available real memory and most of the swap.

So we moved the database files to a bigger server and subsequently ran into the dreaded `db_dump185: seq: invalid argument` error.  I don't believe db_dump185 has a repair function, but I haven't done all the research that I want to do yet.

Comment: What does your `ulimit -a` return?

Comment: core file size          (blocks, -c) 200000
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) 200000
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 32743
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 200000
open files                      (-n) 100
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 20

Comment: virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 200000
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

Comment: Hmm, I should have applied some markup to the comments, I guess?  Sorry.

Comment: OK, file size there unlimited. How big is your database?

Comment: $ ls -l comment.db  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 daiello  staff  184393728 Jan 12  2012 comment.db

Comment: What's the secret to putting line breaks into comments using mini-Markdown?

Comment: You don't put line breaks in comments.  You update your question with the additional information people are looking for.

Comment: aIt could be a Large File Support thing. Is the dump file about 2 gigs when it dies? If that's the problem, you should be able to work around it by outputting to a pipe. `db_dump185 comment.db | cat > comment.dump`.